Patching frame title failed in MacTex 2024
I have an error when compiling a theme derived from the metropolis beamer theme using MacTeX 2024 version. Specifically, the following line in beamerfontthememetropolis.sty will throw out an error called "Patching frame title failed".
\patchcmd{\beamer@@frametitle}
  {{%
       \gdef\insertframetitle{{#2\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space%
       \usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}%
     \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
     \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}%
     }}
   {{%
       \gdef\insertframetitle{{\metropolis@frametitleformat{#2}\ifnum%
       \beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space%
       \usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}%
     \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
     \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}%
     }}
   {}
   {\PackageError{beamerfontthememetropolis}{Patching frame title failed}\@ehc}

I think the frametitle was defined differently. In MacTex 2024 version, it is defined as:
2024
> \beamer@@frametitle=\long macro:
[#1]#2->\ifblank {#2}{}{\gdef \insertframetitle {{#2\ifnum \beamer@autobreakcount >0\relax {}\space \usebeamertemplate *{frametitle continuation}\fi }}\gdef \beamer@frametitle {#2}\gdef \beamer@shortframetitle {#1}}.
l.9 \show\beamer@@frametitle

But in MacTex 2022 version, it was defined as follows, and it won't throw out an error.
2022                            
> \beamer@@frametitle=\long macro:
[#1]#2->\ifblank {#2}{}{\gdef \insertframetitle {{#2\ifnum \beamer@autobreakcount >0 \relax {}\space \beamer@insertframetitlecontinuation \fi }}\gdef \beamer@frametitle {#2}\gdef \beamer@shortframetitle {#1}}.
l.9 \show\beamer@@frametitle

Can anyone let me know how to modify beamerfontthememetropolis.sty so that it won't throw out an error in MacTeX 2024 version?
EDIT: See complete .log file here.

use the moloch theme instead of metropolis.

I also have this question. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks @UlrikeFischer! However I would still like to stick to metropolis.

welcome! please provide a complete example people can compile to reproduce the error. that's much more useful than fragments. could you say what you don't like about moloch? it may be easier to tweak that than fix metropolis.

@cfr Thank you! You can see an example in the Github Repository here. The related code see paper_slides/code.

sorry but imho metropolis has so many problems that it is not worth my time. Also I won't follow a link to debug your code, you would have to provide a small example here.

but it works fine in my texlive 2024, beamer contains a patch to handle metropolis, see also https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/802. So check if your files are all up-to-date.

questions here should be self-contained so they remain useful even when the contents of external links changes. so please make a small example and post the code here if updating your files doesn't do the trick.

@ShiqiYang Did you actually try moloch? It will look nearly identical to metropolis. And if there are details which look different, they can be made to look the same as metropolis.

Can you show your .log file?

as others said, this error shouldn't happen with an up-to-date beamer version. However to resolve the underlying cause, you should make the metropolis maintainer accept this patch: https://github.com/matze/mtheme/pull/391/files

@LaTeXLoVeR Please show your .log file

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
However to resolve the underlying cause, you should make the metropolis maintainer accept this patch: github.com/matze/mtheme/pull/391/files
Confirming this perfectly solves the issue. Thank you!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz @UlrikeFischer Thanks both!
I can still compile PDF without such fix from LaTeX compiler (such as Overleaf), but I cannot use pdflatex slides.tex command to compile from command line in the terminal, as it will be stuck in "Patching frame title failed".

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Could you please post an answer then? I can accept so this issue can be resolved. Thanks!

@ShiqiYang Please show your .log file so we can see why you get this error.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks! The log file is as follows:
! Package beamerfontthememetropolis Error: Patching frame title failed.
See the beamerfontthememetropolis package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...
l.321 ...polis}{Patching frame title failed}@ehc}
Try typing    to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X   to quit.

@ShiqiYang Please add the complete .log file to your question, so we can see which version of beamer you use and if there might be local files which interfere with it.

(if the .log file is too long for the question, you could post it on something like github, https://pastebin.com/ etc.)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you! That works for me. I've updated my comment accordingly.

Beamer's duck-tape solution to avoid the error only works with the exact file names of the metropolis theme, not renamed files like ./beamer_themes/beamerthememetropolis_gslab.sty

That makes sense. We just want to customize our theme so we slightly modified ours.

@ShiqiYang That's a bad idea. Make a new theme, say gslab, which loads the metropolis (or better moloch) theme and then make your modifications there.

The metropolis theme is broken and is no longer compatible with the current beamer version. Attempts to submit patches to the metropolis theme remained unsuccessful, see e.g. https://github.com/matze/mtheme/pull/391/files
(see also the start of this talk for an overview of the current problems in metropolis: https://youtu.be/eupIcENqj00?t=29609 )
To avoid breaking lots of existing presentations, beamer tries to stick some band aids onto the theme. Metropolis users won't be able to enjoy all the features of a current beamer, but at least they don't get an error message. The mechanism beamer uses for this is based on the file names used by the metropolis theme. It won't work with renamed files like beamerthememetropolis_gslab.sty.
Solution
Switch to the moloch theme. It is a maintained fork of the metropolis theme, in which a lot of problems have been fixed.
